# What is libcurl doing with the third parameter on curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, function) in C

Tags: c, curl, libcurl

I'm doing a simple program that gets data from a api and following the documentation I'm creating a callback function to pass to curl_easy_setopt:

```
size_t callback_libcurl(void *contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp) {                                                                                   
        size_t realsize = size * nmemb;                                                                                                                                   
        struct resultado *mem = (struct resultado *)userp;                                                                                                                
                                                                                                                                                                      
        char *ptr = realloc(mem->dados, mem->tamanho + realsize + 1);                                                                                                     
        if(ptr == NULL) {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
              printf("not enough memory (realloc returned NULL)\n");                                                                                                          
              return 0;                                                                                                                                                       
}
```

And then passing that to:

`curl_easy_setopt(handler_curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, callback_libcurl);`

Everything is working but I have no idea why. How I am passing the callback function to the curl function like that?
The docs say the parameter can be a long, a function pointer, an object pointer or a curl_off_t.
It is none of that afaik.
The only source I could find something was:

`CURL_EXTERN CURLcode curl_easy_setopt(CURL *curl, CURLoption option, ...);`

on /curl/easy.h but that does not help either, I don't know what ... is. Could not find anything on it.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The docs say the parameter can be a long, a function pointer, an object pointer or a curl_off_t. It is none of that afaik.

In C a function automatically decays to a function pointer when appropriate. So the following are equivalent:

```
curl_easy_setopt(handler_curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, callback_libcurl);
curl_easy_setopt(handler_curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, &callback_libcurl);
```

Therefore you *are* passing a function pointer, one pointing to `callback_libcurl`.

Comment: Found another answer with: "... After determining the type of each parameter, any parameter of type “array of T” or “function returning T” is adjusted to be “pointer to T” or “pointer to function returning T,” respectively..." from the c++ (?) standard.
I guess that settles it, thank you very much.